# Check my answer for harmonic conjugate of $e^x Sin(y)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m new to the topic
Can someone please check my answer for harmonic conjugate of $U(x,y)=e^x Sin(y)$?

My answer is $V(x,y)=-e^x Cos(y)+C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

First let's check that $u(x,y)$ is a harmonic function, that is it satisfies the  two-dimensional *Laplace equation*
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2 }u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=0 
\end{equation}
Since $\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}=e^x\sin(y)$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=-e^{x}\sin(y)$, we conclude that $u(x,y)$ is harmonic.

Next, we find a harmonic conjugate to $u(x,y)$. We have \begin{equation*}
u_{x}=v_{y} \iff e^{x}\sin(y)=v_{y}
\end{equation*}
So integrating with respect to $y$
\begin{equation}
v(x,y)=-e^{x}\cos(y)+f(x) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $f(x)$ is a function depending only on $x$. We can determine this function from the Cauchy-Riemann equation $-u_{y}=v_{x}$ , which gives
\begin{align*}
-u_{y}=v_{x} &\iff -e^{x}\cos(y)=-e^{x}\cos(y)+f'(x) \\
&\iff f'(x)=0
\end{align*}
Then integrating with respect to $x$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
f(x)=C
\end{equation}
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Therefore the harmonic conjugate f $u(x,y)$ is given by $$v(x,y)=-e^{x}\cos(y)+C$$

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)